# Execute a stored procedure with JSON as input

Tags: sql-server, ssms

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveJson] 
    @pID int, 
    @pJson varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    insert into [dbo].[ShowJson]
        ([id]
        ,[Data])
    values
        (@pID, @pJson)
END
```

I have a procedure SaveJson in my sql server. How should I execute this procedure by passing json file as input to the procedure in SQl Server Management Studio (SSMS).

Thank You in advance